# Is there a Python wrapper for Stanford Neural Net based dependency parser?

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, neural-network, stanford-nlp

I know about the Python wrappers for Stanford CoreNLP package but this package does not seem to contain neural net based dependency parser model. Rather it is present in Stanford-parser-full-****-**-** package for which I can't find any Python wrapper. **My Question: Is there a Python wrapper that would parse using Stanford Neural Net based dependency parser?** Any suggestions or directions would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any such wrapper at the moment, and there are no plans at Stanford to build one. (Maybe the NLTK developers would be up for the challenge?)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Appreciate it!